# need help understanding "elementsFromPoint(x,y)"

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I looked over to this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint

for understanding the elementsFromPoint function. It said the function will return the topmost Element object located at the specified coordinates. It also said that

**x: The horizontal coordinate of a point, relative to the left edge of the current viewport** 
**y:The vertical coordinate of a point, relative to the top edge of the current viewport.**

But I am still confused about it. **Does x refers to the distance from left border of the viewport and y refers to the distance from top border of the viewport (like coordinates (width and height) in a 2D plane)??**

If they represent coordinates in a 2D plane **how does the function knows or retrieves the topmost element at that coordinates since it is just a point on the plane and the topmost element can be any direction from the point**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's like having a laser and your are on the top of your page and you target one point. The element that you touch is the element you  get. That point will have it's x/y defined based on the viewport (the top/left corner)

Comment: => The premise is erroneous, it is not a 2D plane, it is a 3D plane. There is a stack order, known as z-index. "Top most" means the element that has the highest z-index (on top of the layer stack).

Comment: thanks for your comments. so if we use "getBoundingClientRect()" it gives 8 values (left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height) representing 4 coordinates of a rectangle. so for example, the function "elementFromPoint(x, y)" will return the element at top/left corner of the rectangle for given bottom(x) and right(y) coordinates of the rectangle???

Answer (score -1):

Since SVG does not have a Z-index... does this not apply to SVG?  It appears to get elements in the order they are in the SVG document... so the lowest visual layer appears first in the order.